# Calculate average cpu utilisation for app service plan

Tags: azure-powershell

How I can get the average cpu and memory utilisation for app service plan in Azure using powershell cmdlet get-azmetric for one month. I have tried it by taking granularity as 01:00:00:00 ie for one day and calculating average of all the values for one day but when I match with portal it does not tally with my output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my test, the metrics are basically correct, there are some deviation because of the UI in the portal.

> when I match with portal it does not tally with my output

If they are far apart, you should make sure you select the `UTC/GMT` option in the portal(by defalut is `Local`), becasue the `TimeStamp` in the output of the `Get-AzMetric` is `UTC` time(the parameters `StartTime` and `EndTime` are both `local` time).

[image]

---

**Verification steps:**

1.In the portal, easily we can find the `TimeGrain` of the metric is `06:00:00`, so I also use the same one in the powershell command.

[image]

[image]

```
$metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/joyplan" -MetricName "CpuPercentage" -AggregationType Average -TimeGrain 06:00:00 -StartTime 2020-03-07T04:00:00Z -EndTime 2020-04-07T04:00:00Z
$metric.Data
```

[image]

Then in the portal, use dev tool to catch the request of the metric, check it in the [JSON validater](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), it will be like below.

[image]

Compare the values of powershell output and request in portal, we will find they are the same. But you should **note**, the `StartTime` will affect the starting value, the values in the UI is different from that in the API in the background, this is why I compare the powershell ouptput with the API request of portal, the `MemoryPercentage` is the same logic.

So in conclusion, you can use the `Get-AzMetric`, the `TimeGrain` and other parameters are all depending on your requirements.

```
$metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/joyplan" -MetricName "CpuPercentage" -AggregationType Average -TimeGrain 01:00:00:00 -StartTime 2020-03-07T04:00:00Z -EndTime 2020-04-07T04:00:00Z
$metric.Data

$metric = Get-AzMetric -ResourceId "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/joyplan" -MetricName "MemoryPercentage" -AggregationType Average -TimeGrain 01:00:00:00 -StartTime 2020-03-07T04:00:00Z -EndTime 2020-04-07T04:00:00Z
$metric.Data
```